# Stream different data types

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm getting my head around Streams API.

What is happening with the **2** in the first line? What data type is it treated as? Why doesn't this print **true**?

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("hi", "there",2).anyMatch(i->i=="2"));
```

The second part of this question is why doesn't the below code compile (**2 is not in quotes**)?

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("hi", "there",2).anyMatch(i->i==2));
```

Comment: The `2` in your stream is treated as an Integer

Comment: Elements of Stream, are Serializables, that's why You have Strings next to int.

Comment: Also, never compare strings with ==.  Always use .equals().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first snippet, you are creating a `Stream` of `Object`s. The `2` element is an `Integer`, so comparing it to the `String` "2" returns false.

In the second snippet, you can't compare an arbitrary Object to the `int` 2, since there is no conversion from `Object` to `2`.

For the first snippet to return true, you have to change the last element of the Stream to a `String` (and also use `equals` instead of `==` in order not to rely on the `String` pool):

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("hi", "there", "2").anyMatch(i->i.equals("2")));
```

The second snippet can be fixed by using `equals` instead of `==`, since `equals` exists for any `Object`:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("hi", "there",2).anyMatch(i->i.equals(2)));
```

Comment: You'd beat me in the details I guess :)

Answer (score 3):

You should instead make use of:

```
System.out.println(Stream.of("hi", "there",2).anyMatch(i->i.equals(2)));
```

The reason for that is the comparison within the `anyMatch` you're doing is for `i` which is an `Object`(from the stream) and is incompatible with an `int`.

Also, note that the first part compiles successfully since you are comparing an integer(object) with an object string `"2"` in there and hence returns false.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Even with the .equals method it still returns false. Why do you feel that is?

Comment: @JonJavaK It should return **true** with `.equals(2)` unless you're again comparing it with `.equals("2")`